# PL/SQL Insert check

Tags: oracle, plsql

Just having a problem with ensuring a constraint is not violated.

Goal: To insert a record that does not violate a constraint.

Constraint: An order should not be allowed if it is discontinued or out of stock.

Now I have a procedure that I was working on and have the necessary syntax working. Just need the finishing touches to get this insert procedure working.

```
/* Creating Procedure */
CREATE PROCEDURE INSERT_ORDER_DETAIL(
--PARAMETERS
    p_product_name IN VARCHAR,
    p_unit_price IN NUMBER,
    p_quantity IN NUMBER,
    p_discount IN NUMBER) IS

--VARIABLES AND DECLARATION FOR PROCEDURE
    p_order_id NUMBER;
    PRODUCT_LIST PRODUCT%ROWTYPE;
    Fail EXCEPTION;

BEGIN
-- Check for product availability
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        INTO PRODUCT_LIST
        FROM PRODUCT
        WHERE DISCONTINUED = 'N'; -- select all orders available
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR ! PRODUCT IS UNAVAILABLE');
            RAISE Fail;
    END;

--generate new order ID    
    SELECT MAX(ORDER_ID)+1
    INTO p_order_id
    FROM ORDER_DETAIL;

-- INSERTING A NEW ORDER
    INSERT INTO ORDER_DETAIL VALUES (p_order_id, p_product_name, p_unit_price, p_quantity, p_discount);
    COMMIT;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DONE!');
EXCEPTION
    WHEN Fail THEN
        ROLLBACK;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
        ROLLBACK;
END INSERT_ORDER_DETAIL;
/
```

Comment: Why this question is MySQL-tagged?

Comment: You say your procedure is working. So what is your actual question? What are you expecting from us?

Comment: By the way, we don't know your data model but usually `ORDERS` and `ORDER_DETAILS` are two different things, reflecting multiple items in an order. It seems a bit odd that your procedure generates a new `order_id` for every item, and it doesn't pass it back to the caller. Also, the normal naming convention is `p_` for parameters and something else for variables and constants. `p_order_id` is not a parameter, so what does the `p` stand for?

Comment: There is a subtle bug in your code: "SELECT MAX(ORDER_ID)+1". In a multi-user environment this guarantees that at some point you will get a duplicate id generated. How? Two users call your procedure at the same instant, each runs the above statement and since a commit has not been done they each get the same value, then the inserts. One succeeds, one gets exception. Good luck finding the source of the error. Solution use a sequence to generate the id.

Answer (score 1):

You have two simple approaches, implement either of them.

1. In your insert procedure, add an `IF` condition to check whether the product is available in the inventory against the input order, and put the `INSERT` statement inside the IF block. Else, raise an `EXCEPTION` product not available. Similarly check for quantity as well.

Or,

1. Create a `FUNCTION` based on above logic that returns `TRUE` if product exists. You could simply go for the count in the table for that matching product in the function.
2. Based on the function's return value TRUE, call the INSERT procedure. Else, if FALSE, raise an exception that product is not available.

Put all the functions,  procedures in one package.